# Computer causes internet loss on other devices

Tags: internet, windows-8.1, connection, switch, packet-loss

I have a switch that is directly connected to my modem. attached to this switch are a computer, PS3, PS4 and a NAS. They all have been assigned static IP addresses. My problem is the following:

Whenever I play Playstation (3 or 4, doesn't matter) I get logged out very, very often. Almost 5 minutes into logging in. I thought it might be a broken switch, so I exchanged it with a new one, but the problem still persists.

Yesterday, however I could play for hours without logging out, what I found weird after all..
I looked to my left and noticed that I turned down my PC, so I wanted to test what would happen if I turned it on. And yes.. Right after pressing the power button on my PC, I get logged out within the minute on the Playstation.

So there we go, My PC is the problem with my internet. But... I have no idea what could cause all of this. I turn to you guys to see what I can check.

My PC runs on W8.1 (formatted last week), it doesn't have much apps to work with.

I truly hope some of you have an idea what could be the issue and help me resolve it.

Comment: What IP addresses do your devices use?

Comment: When you play the Playstation, you get logged out of what? The account? Does this mean it doesn't have access to the router? Very good first question, +1. I wonder if you have an IP conflict. How is the PC getting it's IP, dynamic via the router I assume? However, it would be good to plug all 4 devices into the router direct to see if the same problem persists when turning the PC on...

Comment: I have static Ip adresses for my devices.

I get logged out of parties, games and my account lastly. Itried to run my PS' without my PC plugged in and they played fine, so it is the PC..

Comment: Can you try making your PC dynamic. As I said, it sounds like a conflict (some how)... I wonder if there is caching issue with the router or something similar. Make the PC dynamic turn it off, try PS machines and then turn PC on again

Comment: I will try that. Although my pc is not in conflict with my other devices, but it's worth a try. Thx! I am still open for more solutions though :p

Answer (score 1):

Okay I got it fixed; I did two things actually and I am not sure what the actual problem solver is.

First, someone told me it could possibly be my torrent application. And it was indeed running when my pc started up. So I uninstalled it. I also reassigned my Ip address to another one. From 100 to 150.

Now it works like a charm. No disconnections, I do not leave parties anymore all of a sudden.
I hope this helps people in the future! and Thx for aiding me!

Comment: Your torrent application was creating so many connections to peers on the internet that your router couldn't handle it. Seems that you really need a better router or your torrent application is seriously badly configured. This is actually a quite common phenomenon. Cheap routers (or old ones) typically can't cope well with many simultaneous connections (like torrents). And torrent applications usually have settings to limit the traffic they cause so they can be set to be more friendly to the network.

Comment: As a matter of fact; I recently just installed it without configuring it properly, which is why it caused the problem. I uninstalled it since I won't use my computer to DL anymore. I got a NAS now :D

Answer (score 0):

That is a good question.

It is hard to answer this question without additional detail, but the first and most logical guess would be conflicting IP addresses on the network.

This is easy to check if you are familiar with your router settings.

- open command prompt on your windows machine and type `ipconfig`
- take a note of the iIP address of your `Default Gateway`
- open your browser and try to connect to this IP address
- you may be asked for password (this should be supplied with your
  router)
- Check the LAN settings - typically router will provide you a list of
  devices by MAC address with IP address assigned to every one.
- Make sure that you can identify every device on your network and that
  none of them are using the same IP address.
- Also make sure that all MAC addresses are different (these are very
  unlikely to match but you never know, someone could have been playing
  with settings).
- If there is an ip conflict, then you can either reset all DHCP leases
  or manually assign IP addresses to some/all devices.

Good luck, and welcome to SU

Comment: It might have been wise of me to have added that I already assigned static IP addresses to my devices. So I can exclude IP address conflict for almost 90%. but hey, I can always still test it out! thx!